# Navigation menu with JavaScript enabled effect

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom-events, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to make a navigation menu with JavaScript enabled effect, but each menu item has both an 'a' and an 'i' tag, and would need to enable both at the same time.
Basically the html menu is simple;

```
<div class="menu-nav">
        <ul class="menu-nav-list">
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a href="#" class="menu-nav-link ativo"><i class="uil uil-estate menu-nav-link-icon active-icon"></i> Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a href="#" class="menu-nav-link"><i class="uil uil-user menu-nav-link-icon"></i> About me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a href="#" class="menu-nav-link"><i class="uil uil-bag menu-nav-link-icon"></i> Works</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a href="#" class="menu-nav-link"><i class="uil uil-envelope-minus menu-nav-link-icon"></i> Contact me</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

But in the JS code I try to manipulate the array that has all the items and I can only use 'this' to activate a specific item in 'forEach'

```
const iconesLink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-nav-link-icon')
const itemsLink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-nav-link')
itemsLink.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', activeLink, activeIcon))

function activeLink(){
  itemsLink.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('ativo'))
  this.classList.add('ativo')
}


function activeIcon(){
  iconesLink.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active-icon'))
  this.forEach(l => l.classList.add('active-icon'))
}
```

Would there be another method that I could activate both the  and the  with just one click event?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The eventTarge.addEventListener takes just one event handler function. The function is called with an object which has the target clicked as property target `{ target: the element that was clicked }`.

I'm getting the clicked element in the listener and calling the other two functions.

In the activeIcon function we can get a reference to the selected icon by calling querySelector on the clicked a tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="menu-nav">
        <ul class="menu-nav-list">
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a href="#" class="menu-nav-link ativo"><i class="uil uil-estate menu-nav-link-icon active-icon"></i> Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a href="#" class="menu-nav-link"><i class="uil uil-user menu-nav-link-icon"></i> About me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a href="#" class="menu-nav-link"><i class="uil uil-bag menu-nav-link-icon"></i> Works</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a href="#" class="menu-nav-link"><i class="uil uil-envelope-minus menu-nav-link-icon"></i> Contact me</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script>
const iconesLink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-nav-link-icon')
const itemsLink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-nav-link')
itemsLink.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
  activeLink(event.target) 
  activeIcon(event.target.querySelector('.menu-nav-link-icon'))
}))

function activeLink(current){
  itemsLink.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('ativo'));
  current.classList.add('ativo')
}


function activeIcon(current){
  iconesLink.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active-icon'));
  current.classList.add('active-icon');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what you did. Providing code without an explanation is not very helpful.